# WPF-проект не обновляется после компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Возникла проблема. Захожу в свой wpf проект, делаю изменения, компилю, но все остается как при взоде, никакие изменения не происходят. Что нужно поменять, чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: 1. попробуйте rebuild
2. внесите ошибочный код, посмотрите, поменяется ли что-то. бросьте исключение и не ловите, например.
3. а не запускаете ли вы вместо вашей программы какую-то другую (свойства проекта -> Debug -> Start Action)? или может у вас две функции Main? или не тот Startup Project?

Comment: пересоберите проект, в студии давно уже не работал, не помню точное сочетание клавишь (Shift+Ctrl+B что то такое) посмотрите во вкладке "Project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, вроде бы решил проблему, решение такое: Проект -> Пакетное построение, и там ставим галочки на сборках, которые на нужны.